# How to bind one angular model to the value of another ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I have a radio button being selected like this:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="lesson.sectionID" value="{{section.$id}}">
```

I want to bind the value of that input to another model, I tried the following:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="module.sectionID" ng-bind="lesson.sectionID">
```

and

```
<input type="text" ng-model="module.sectionID" ng-value="lesson.sectionID">
```

When I tried ng-value it set the text input to the correct value but the actual value of the model was not being set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably looking for this solution

```
angular.module('choices', [])
  .controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.color = '';

    $scope.colors = [
      "Red",
      "Green",
      "Blue",
      ""
     ];

    $scope.changeColor = function(){
      $scope.color = "Red"
    };

}]);



<html>
<head>
<body ng-app="choices" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="color in colors">
     <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.color" ng-value="color" id="{{color}}" name="color">
       <label >
         {{color || 'Other'}}
       </label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.color" ng-show="color==''">
  </div>
  <p></p>
  The chosen color is <strong>{{color}}</strong>
  <p></p>
  <button ng-click="changeColor()">Change color</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign your model using

```
ng-model="module.sectionID"
ng-value="module.sectionID=lesson.sectionID"
```